# Can not find entity of the oneToOne relation

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

```
public class Maintenance implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "maintenance_issue_mod",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "maintenance_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "issue_mod_id"))
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<IssueMod> issueMod = new HashSet<>();


@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = COrder.class)
@NotNull
@NotFound(
        action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumn(name="c_order_id", nullable = false, insertable = false,
        updatable = false)
private COrder cOrder;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
private Invoice invoice;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "referred_invoice_id")
private Invoice referredInvoice;
 getter and setter
```

this is the Maintenance class and relation of the Maintenance and COrder  is OneToOne .

this is corder class

```
public class COrder implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@CreatedDate
@NotNull
@Column(name = "created", nullable = false)
private Instant created = Instant.now();

@Size(max = 255)

@NotNull
@Column(name = "order_number", length = 255, nullable = false, unique = true)
private String orderNumber;



 Maintenance maintenance = maintenanceRepository.findById(maintenanceInvoiceDTO.getMaintenanceId());
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  " +maintenance);
    COrder currentOrder = cOrderRepository.findOneById(maintenance.getcOrder().getId());
```

in the service to find the maintenance through the maintenanceId 
then we get the following error 
'Unable to find in.bsrnetwork.ctrack.domain.COrder with id 1'
but the corder id 1 is present in the the corder table

Comment: you are facing issue at the following line ? 
`COrder currentOrder = cOrderRepository.findOneById(maintenance.getcOrder().getId());`

Comment: I wonder what the JPA providers log says ...

Comment: Maintenance maintenance = maintenanceRepository.findById(maintenanceInvoiceDTO.getMaintenanceId());  getting the error on that line i.e in themaintenance table what ever corder id is persent is not persent in the corder despite it is persent in the corder table